# How do I calculate offset functions of these circuts? (Matlab results vs analytical results vary)

Tags: transfer-function

I am trying to calculate offset functions of these circuts but, the offsets results I got from matlab vary from those I calculated in python(analitically).

So I have three circuts, and after each circut I'll write down a function I thought was right, and the results from both matlab and calculus.

G11 is a transfer function of the first block while looking from the start of the circut.

G12 is a transfer function of the second block while looking from the start of the circut.

H1 is a block on feedback loop.

A is a amplitude of the noise applied in various points of the circut

1)
[image]

Offset function I wrote:

```
E_u1_1 = (1/(1 + G11*G12))*1 (times 1 is a step signal)
```

Matlab result: 0.71

calculated result: 0.8

2)
[image]

Function:

```
E_u1_2 = (1/(1 + G11*G12))*1 + (G12/(1 + G11*G12))*(-A)
```

Matlab Result: 0.1713

Calculated result:0.552

3)
[image]

Function:

```
E_u1_4 = (1/(1 + G11*G12))*1 + (G11*G12)*(-A)
```

Matlab Result: 0.1713

Calculated result:0.7225

Are those formulas wrong? If so where? Can someone correct me?

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT:
Later on to calculate the precise value of the offset I used the formula:

```
es={lim(s->0)}s*Offset_function
```

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP! It's not clear to me what you mean by **offset**.  Do you mean the final value, as per Dan's answer? For example, what is `Offset_function` in your final line?

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the issue is in assuming that a step is 1. The Laplace transform of the unit step is $1/s$. Additionally, to get the final value (if that is what the OP means by offset?), use the final value theorem which is multiplying the resulting expression by $s$ and take the limit as $s \rightarrow 0$.

I will elaborate further, using the first case; in general the closed loop transfer function is given as

$$G_{CL}(s) = \frac{G_F(s)}{1 + G_{OL(s)}}$$

Where $G_F(s)$ is the forward gain from input to output and $G_{OL}(s)$ is the open loop gain. For the OP's first case, case each of these are as follows using the OP's conventions:

$$G_F(s) = G_{11}(s) G_{12}(s)$$

$$G_{OL}(s) = 10 G_{11}(s) G_{12}(s)$$

Thus the closed loop transfer function is:

$$G_{CL}(s) = \frac{G_{11}(s) G_{12}(s)}{1 + 10 G_{11}(s) G_{12}(s)}$$

The inverse Laplace Transform of this would be the Impulse Response (which is the case of the input being 1, since the Laplace Transform of an impulse is 1.)

If we wanted to know the step response, we would take the inverse Laplace Transform of $G_{CL}(s)/s$ as described above, and if we wanted to know the final value of a step, then we would multiply that by $s$, which would then again be $G_{CL}(s)$ and take the limit of that as $s \rightarrow 0$.